# Why can’t I play a German Aladdin Broadway CD with an external CD drive connected to my 2020 MacBook Air?

Tags: mac, compact-disc, music

I really liked the original soundtrack of the Aladdin Broadway musical, so I wanted to listen to all of the songs in German. I bought this (used) CD from an American company and the CD arrived today. The packaging looks new and the CD has no scratches.

However, when I tried to use my 2020 MacBook Air with macOS 13 (Ventura) to play it (using an external CD drive), it didn't play. The drive just ejected it. I also tried playing it on a Sony boombox, but it also didn't play.

Why doesn't it play? Will I be able to get songs off of it?

Update: It works on the Sony music player and the Sony boombox. I still can't get it to play on the CD/DVD drive, though.

Comment: It depends. There is no technical reason it should not play like DRM or anything. So in my experience either the CD itself is scratched up, or the CD player is picky. I have a 2020 MacBook Air and well and I have two external optical drives just to deal with oddball cases like this. I purchase CDs and rip them to the Apple Music app regularly and for some reason some discs will work in only one of the two drives. And there is no consistency to why this happens.

Comment: Workaround: https://music.apple.com/us/album/aladdin-original-broadway/877812620 & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RANub1QD-4g&list=OLAK5uy_lawOrqYy64aPPcDnRzmK1iSpmlguk0X6M it's on Apple Music and on YouTube so it may be simpler just to get it there.

Comment: @Gantendo Those are not in German, though.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Even better. Anyway, here is the OST in German.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0vbk61rYy4&list=PL6B1m8fIKnRMlGSbEG9Cia3pk_jP6staR

Comment: That's the 2019 live action version. Really awesome, but not the 2011 Broadway verison.

Comment: @ILEMWorld My best advice for the CD you actually have is to simply clean it. Use a lint-free cloth or something you can use to clean glasses or screens to wipe it clean and try again. Maybe even spray rubbing alcohol or spray hand sanitizer (that we have all over thanks to COVID-19) and clean it that way. This is an issue with the CD being read on the external CD reader. Nothing more and nothing less.